# rfc-clueless.org, how to get delisted

Tags: blacklist

I noticed rfc-clueless.org is blocking my .de-domain.

rfc-clueless.org say:

> Imported from whois.rfc-ignorant.org

But if I try to lookup my domain at rfc-ignorant.org

> dig A *****.de.whois.rfc-ignorant.org +short

It contains no content.

The complete government of germany is blacklisted.

> dig bundesregierung.de.whois.rfc-clueless.org +short

Comment: Follow their removal process? http://rfc-clueless.org/pages/removal_process

Answer (score 3):

rfc-clueless.org blacklist all domains with TLDs which do not run compliant NICNAME/WHOIS servers. (http://rfc-clueless.org/pages/faq#tld)

Therefore they blacklist the domains of a lot of Counties. Not only Germany (.de) but also most other European countries, Mexico, Rusia, China and many more.

Your site cannot get delisted as you have no control over your Country's TLD policies.

I fully support their goal to coerce a better compliance with the RFC standards.

**But:**

Outside the United States it is customary for people, companies and organizations to use their country's TLD for their website. To blacklist the domains of a big part of the world population based on their nationality without them being able to get delisted might be unfair.

Comment: For those of us who try to find the perpetrators of net abuse, it is not merely "unfair" to not publish information which is required by the pertinent RFCs to be public. Publishing information about who violates these policies is not unfair. Using this published information to decide whether or not to accept email from domains which are in violation is a bit heavy-handed (and thus not very common) but clearly a decision which each domain's administrator can and must make on their own. If you are upset, help coerce your country's TLD to comply.